# Create trigger on delete that resets auto increment id if the table is empty on sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a trigger that will reset the auto increment id to 0 if the table have just become empty. I've tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reset_autoincrement AFTER DELETE ON temp WHEN count(*) = 0 
BEGIN
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 0 WHERE name = 'temp';
END
```

Although the SQL seems correct, it doesn't do what I want.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression in the WHEN clause is not in the context of the table; `count(*)` without a table returns `1`.

Use a subquery instead:

```
... WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM temp) = 0 ..
```